# Target class does not exists which is (Target class [App\Http\Controllers\patient] does not exist.) LARAVEL 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

When I insert data into fields and after clicking the save button this error shows up, I think the error is my web route file I have defined the route in two ways but it didn't work, I used same method to insert it into another table in MySQL and it worked but  when I tried to insert data into another table this error shows up, here is my controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use App\patient;

class add1 extends Controller
{
    

    function add1(Request $request){
              $request->validate(
                [
                    'fname'=> 'required',
                    'cnic'=> 'required'
                    
                ]
              );
    


 $query=DB::table('patients')->insert([
'fname'=> $request->input('fname'),
'lname'=> $request->input('lname'),
'cnic'=> $request->input('cnic'),
'contactno'=> $request->input('contactno'),
'gender'=> $request->input('gender'),
'age'=> $request->input('age'),
'dob'=> $request->input('dob'),
'city'=> $request->input('city'),
'address'=> $request->input('address'),
'husbandname'=> $request->input('husbandname'),
'fathername'=> $request->input('fathername'),
'bloodgroup'=> $request->input('bloodgroup'),
'primaryphy'=> $request->input('primaryphy'),
'clientname'=> $request->input('clientname'),
'maritalstatus'=> $request->input('maritalstatus'),
'emergencyno'=> $request->input('emergencyno'),
'category'=> $request->input('category'),

    ]);

if ($query){
    return back()->with ('success','Data has been successfuly inserted!');
}
else{
    return back()->with ('fail','something went wrong');
}

}
}
```

Here is my web.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\login;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;
use App\Http\Controllers\patient;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/




Route::get('/registration', function () {
    return view('registration');
});

Route::post('add1',[patient::class, 'add1']);
```

This my blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.theme')
@section('content')
<style type="text/css">
    .form-control {
        margin-bottom: 10px;

    }
    label{
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .disabled{
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    select.form-control{
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table{
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .wellcometext{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 250px;
        color: black;
    }
    .slogon {
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }
    .wellcometext:hover{
  transition: transform .5s;
    }
    .modal-backdrop {
   background-color: black;}
</style>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top: 50px">

    <h4>User Mangement</h4>
<hr>

@if(Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{Session::get('success')}}
</div>
@endif  

@if(Session::get('fail'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
{{Session::get('fail')}}
</div>
@endif


<form action="add1" method="post">
    @csrf   


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Enter name" value="{{old('name')}}">
    </div>
    <span style="color:red">@error ('name'){{$message}} @enderror</span>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Type</label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="cnic">
                        <option value="0">Select </option>
                        <option value="General">General</option>
                        <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
                        <option value="Consultant">Consultant</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
    
    
       <div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">save</button>
    </div>

</hr>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>  


@endsection
```

Comment: Your controller is named `add1`, not `patient`

Comment: Your Controllers have to have `Controller`suffix.

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli They don't.

Comment: It is not required but for Laravel coding standarts they should have

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli that is not necessary, I have another controller without controller suffix and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all please compare your `controller fileName` with `controller className`

[image: target-class-does-not-exists-which-is-target-class-app-http-controllers-patien-reason]

As you have shown in your `controller` snippet, your class has the name `add1`, not `patient`.

2. In the above image you have called `App\patient` & `App\patient`, make sure your models must exist in the `app` directory because In `laravel8` models are allocated in the `App\models` directory.
3. In your `web.php` route file. You are calling `patient` instead you have to call `controller` class which is `add1`.

[image: wrong controller class calling that is not existed]